# Aspnet API controller parameter not deserializing correctly

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json.net

I'm pretty new to C# and ASP.NET. I have an API controller with this action method:

```
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;

namespace Mautic.Webhook 
{
    [ApiController]
    [Route("mautic/[controller]")]
    public class WebhookController : ControllerBase
    {
        public WebhookController(ILogger<WebhookController> logger)
        {
            Logger = logger;
        }

        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult WebhookAction(WebhookRequest data)
        {
            Logger.LogInformation(ObjectDumper.Dump(data.LeadPostDelete));
            return NoContent();
        }

        private ILogger<WebhookController> Logger { get; }
    }
}
```

And have this definition of `WebhookRequest`:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using Newtonsoft.Json;

namespace Mautic 
{
    public class ContactWebhookRequest 
    {
        public int id { get; set; }
        public string timestamp { get; set; }
    }

    public class WebhookRequest
    {
       [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "mautic.lead_post_delete")]
       public List<ContactWebhookRequest> LeadPostDelete { get; set; }
       public string timestamp { get; set; }
    }
}
```

When I receive data in the controller I want it to deserialize to my class but I got null on `LeadPostDelete` property. Does ASP.NET understand the Newtonsoft `JsonProperty` attribute? Or do I need to migrate it to `System.Text.Json`?

Also migrating to `System.Text.Json` is enough or I will need to deserialize this by hand on my controller?

Comment: What is the JSON request that you are sending and what is the content-type?

Comment: .Net core from version 3 "understands" both (but only one can be configured at once I think). You can figure out which one did you configure to use. I think System.Text.Json is default, so Newtonsoft attribute won't work out of the box

Comment: `application/json` and an example of request data can be found here: https://gist.github.com/dhilst/046227d3d0e9d05b055c92fcbec72ac7

Comment: Ilya, I want to keep with "out of the box" solution, so migrating to System.text.Json should help me right? Do I need to install System.Text.Json? I saw that in the MS docs, it doesn't really make much sense to me

Comment: @IlyaChernomordik thanks, I migrated to System.Text.Json, now I'm getting a validation error, there should be a mismatch between my class and the received JSON, I will do further investigation thank you again!

Comment: Your mismatch is most likely because you have a nullable property id. It cannot be assigned to `int`, you have to use int? (nullable int)

Comment: Yeah, is that and because field ids are ints on delete hook and string on create hook (facepalm), 

https://gist.github.com/dhilst/046227d3d0e9d05b055c92fcbec72ac7#file-mautic-webhook-request-json-L19

https://gist.github.com/dhilst/046227d3d0e9d05b055c92fcbec72ac7#file-mautic-webhook-request-json-L792

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`JsonProperty` attribute does exist in both "old" `Newtonsoft.Json` that was default in `.Net Core` before version 3. You are probably using the new `System.Text.Json` that won't understand this attribute out of the box.

You need probably to use the attribute from that namespace. Otherwise ensure that you use the same serialization and attribute anyway.

Answer (score 0):

If you want avoid refactoring on migrating to 3+ you should to force controllers to use Newtonsoft.Json:

https://dotnetcoretutorials.com/2019/12/19/using-newtonsoft-json-in-net-core-3-projects/

Sorry for My English.